# Display Asset Images in GridView in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

I want to display a list of images from assets in GridView. And I'm not able to do that. I want to know the data type for a list of images from the assets and how a constructor would help in this case. I've just started to learn flutter and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: You should consider adding what you've tried so far and why it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GridView` or `GridView.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) and [`Image.asset`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html). Note that add asset in `pubspec.yaml` file ([more](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)). You can find more information about GridView [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html).

```dart
GridView.builder(
 itemCount: 2,
 gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  childAspectRatio: 1,
 ),
 itemBuilder: (ctx, index){
    return Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png');
 },
)
```

Comment: Thank You I achieved that ... <3